# How to run c++ within Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I wrote a small C++ program in Xcode 4.6. I used an empty C++ class to create the file, and then added a simple Cocoa application template, hence creating the app as the target.

This is the content of the .cpp file:

```
#include "tempConv.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int temp;
    char inputScale = 'X';

    cout << "Enter temp:";
    cin >> temp;
    cout << "Enter F or C:";
    cin >> inputScale;

    if (inputScale=='F') {
        temp = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
        cout << "Centigrade equivalent is " << temp << endl;
    }
    else if (inputScale=='C')  {
        temp = (temp * 9 / 5) + 32;
        cout << "Fahrenheit equivalent is " << temp << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << "Invalid input - try again later" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The C++ file has a main, so it is necessary to suppress the standard main.m that comes with the application.

When I run the file, it's not connected in any way to the UI. The inputs and outputs appear in the debug outputs view.

Is there a way to call the cpp file from the main.m file, or some other way to connect it to the UI?

Comment: If you rename your `main.m` to `main.mm` you will be able to easily mingle ObjC and C++.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the project make it a command line app, then you can use any language you want

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The command line app works, but output goes to the debug window. Is there a way to connect the output to a proper UI?

Comment: well once you have the code shouldn't you be able to put the output where ever you want. Also you can make a UI in xcode as im sure you know

Comment: I basically don't understand how to inject the C++ code into the standard xcode logic for managing a UI. Using a command line template for the C++ code does not provide a means to output to a UI.